# How to not redirect to another form without submitting a password change form using devise in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, form-submit, change-password

when being on a **password** change form **(devise gem)** in **ruby on rails**, it should not redirect to another form without submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to tell what you want exactly, but in general you can modify Devise controllers to suit your needs.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers